# Accessing user information from instagram without user logging

Tags: instagram, user-data

I am working on an iphone app which uses instagram API..and I would like to know the following things..Is it possible to get data from instagram without user logging?If so, what type of data would be retrieved from it?Is it possible to access data of a specified user?Or is it only possible using social networking sites like facebook,tumblr etc?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with a valid **client id**, you can fetch user information for a specific user id. Information available includes name, bio, website, and profile picture. You can also return multiple users' data using the search endpoint.

Take a look at the User Endpoints documented here: http://instagr.am/developer/endpoints/users/

I also suggest reading **Do you need to authenticate?** section here: http://instagr.am/developer/authentication/

**NOTE**: by providing a client id instead of a valid user token, you are counting against your own application's 5000 calls per-hour limit. If you plan on having a large user page, you would need to authenticate each user to avoid this limit.